# SetContentView с анимацией

Tags: android, анимация

Добрый вечер! Вопрос такой: как сделать переход к `setContentView` с помощью анимации? То есть, у меня сначала ставится `R.layout.main`, а потом нужно перейти к `R.layout.afe` с анимацией "сдвиг влево".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для создания подобной анимации необходимо продлать следующие шаги:

Создать в ресурсах папку **anim**, а в ней два файла **slide__in** и **slide__out**

***slide_in.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0" />
</set>
```

***slide_out.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <translate
        android:duration="800"
        android:fromXDelta="0"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
```

Далее в классе из которого будет осуществляться переход, добавляем следующее:

```
public static enum TransitionType {
        SlideLeft
    }

public static TransitionType transitionType;
```

**И естественно:**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Afe.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        transitionType = TransitionType.SlideLeft;
        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in, R.anim.slide_out);
```

Надеюсь правильно понял Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Не совсем правильно, но сильно помогло. Спасибо!